# System files existing on all recent versions of Windows

Tags: windows

What are the system files that can be found on any recent Windows operating system (perhaps since Windows 2000), without any changes? E.g. the same file size and the same binary content?

Comment: Why do you need the information?

Comment: I'd like to use the files that guaranteed to exist on any modern Windows machine as strong encryption keys

Comment: I think there are better methods. How would having the same files help you create a good encryption? Instead  if you want to use binary CRC etc for encryption, use the binary signature of your own dll. That way you will be able to detect tampering. Else go with the std encryption methods available on the net. Do a google.

Comment: Indeed, I'm going to use VERY standard methods. They assume either creating the password that you have to type or the key file that you have to carry around. Now I'd like to use some standard file that I don't have to move between the machines because it exists on any of them.

Answer (score 3):

I think none. Cause Windows is evolving, new underlying technology, new runtime framework etc. So even if for backwards compatibility reasons, microsoft does keep the legacy methods exposed in a dll, they will add new methods, use newer compiler etc. So I think the answer is no.

If you can elaborate on the need for such details, we may be able to suggest some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft tries to assure everyone (and especially their big customers) your old programs still run, that means backwards compatibility and the debt that comes with that. Reading [Raymond Chen's](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/) blog you'll find [many of these small little backwards compatibility "features"](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing+compatibility) (about 577 posts according to Google). Big chance, these files are not changed because external programs depend on it in a static way, and windows either uses a wrapper to add functionality, or uses a whole different set of dll's.

Funny example is the [xerox folder](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/16/258220.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Any of the `.exe` and `.dll` files will be different due to different compile times and version number. System files such as `C:\boot.ini` will have version specific information.

So I would vote for: **none**

Comment: `boot.ini` doesn't even exist on halfway recent Windows versions anymore.